# 'Object is of type unknown' inside map function in VueJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the following function in a setup method in a single page VueJS3 component, which takes an object 'groupedData' from an API and re-formats it for plotting on a chart:

```
const formattedData = Object.entries(groupedData).map(([name, data1]) => ({
  name,
  data: Object.values(data1.reduce((r, { x, y }) => {
    r[x] ?? (r[x] = { x, y: 0 });
    r[x].y += y;
    return r;
  }, {}))
}));
```

I'm getting an error on `data1` where it is being reduced (line 3 above), saying `Object is of type 'unknown'`. This seems to be due to TypeScript not recognising the type. I don't have much experience with TypeScript so wondered what the best way is to address this.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is because `Object.entries()` does not guarantee the order of the data returned, and `name, data1` may not be the order presented. Sort it first for a guarantee and then you can type it appropriately.

Comment: you can try to replace `[name, data1]` with just `x` and refer to `name` as `x[0]` & `data1` as `x[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up breaking this out into separate functions and that resolved the typing issue:

```
const groupByDate = (values) => {
  return Object.values(
    values.reduce((r, { x, y }) => {
      r[x] ?? (r[x] = { x, y: 0 })
      r[x].y += y
      return r
    }, {})
  )
}

return Object.entries(groupedDataByProduct).map(([name, data1]) => ({
  name,
  data: groupByDate(data1),
}))
```